# Session JWTs vs Session Cookies; Misunderstood?

Tags: security, session, cookies, xss, csrf

For a React project, I'm trying to implement some auth solution. The following are what I'm considering.

1. Session Cookies are random tokens saved in HTTP only cookies sent by
   the server. They are vulnerable against CSRF attacks. To protect
   against, CSRF attacks, send a unique identifier with every HTTP
   request. XSS protection is still required.
2. Session JWT are random signed tokens sent by the server. They are
   vulnerable against XSS attacks. No CSRF protection is necessary.

Based off that, I decided to implement a Session JWT due to it being a random token, only need to focus on XSS protection, and session management abilities. In fact, I don't see the point of http only session cookies since an XSS attack can act via the user's browser. Preventing cookie access is barely counted as protection since an XSS attack can fool the user into providing credentials.

However, the more I research into this topic, the more confused I become. I keep getting conflicted info like JWTs being compared to Sessions instead of Cookies, no Session JWT implementations, and comments that state Session Cookies protect against XSS attacks.

Am I misunderstanding Session, Cookies, and/or JWT based off my prior descriptions?

Comment: cookies are client side storage, you could store session information or JWTs in them

Comment: @KeithNicholas Maybe I'm getting mixed up by the terminology. Sessions can be set in JWTs. Sessions and JWTs can be set in Cookies or Local Storage on the Client.